# WPF datagrid styling

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I want to style a WPF datagrid and it seems to be really easy . As far as I understand I have to have code such as the following:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#88800080" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" /> 
</Style>
```

But my question is ..where do I place this code and how do I let the datagrid know to use the style above ?

Regards,
S

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the resource of the xaml (local or global). The easiest is to put it in the local resource of the current xaml file:

```
<Page Name="SomeName"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#88800080" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" /> 
   </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
<!-- The rest of the xaml -->
</Page>
```

Comment: what if I'm using UserControl instead of Page ?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to put styles is in a resource dictionary, referenced in App.xaml.

Resource dictionary ("StyleResources.xaml" in this example):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockRightAlign" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockTitle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Referencing the style dictionary in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StyleResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ValueConverters:PriceConverter x:Key="PriceConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Using the definition in a datagrid (column formatting here, but should work for headers as well):

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Charge" Width="100" 
       Binding="{Binding Charge, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource PriceConverter}}"
       ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBlockRightAlign}" />
```

Note that the element inside the cell is a TextBlock, so you can use a style with a target type of TextBlock.

Answer (score 1):

As for the "Type DataGridColumnHeader was not found": you need a second xml namespace entry since the DataGridColumnHeader is in the System.Windows.Controls.Primitives namespace.  You need something like

```
xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=WPFToolkit"
```

and then reference the new namespace in your style, e.g.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridColumnHeader}" >
```

Comment: Thanks... upgraded versions of WPFToolkit and it looks like the DataGridColumnHeader got split into the new namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Styles usually go:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#88800080" />
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" /> 
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Use the appropriate container if this isn't within a UserControl you may use "Window" or whatever container you're in.

Also you need to reference it in your datagrid with:

```
<Custom:DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
```